# gpg keys failure prevent yum install of Intel libraries

Tags: yum, gnupg, intel-mkl

To install `intel-daal-core-2018.1-163` on CentOS, I used these two repo files:

`/etc/yum.repos.d/intel-mkl.repo`:

```
[intel-mkl-core-2018.1-163]
name='Intel(R) Intel Math Kernel Library'
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl/setup/PUBLIC_KEY.PUB
debuglevel=10
enabled=1
```

`/etc/yum.repos.d/intel-daal.repo`:

```
[intel-daal-core-2018.1-163]
name='Intel(R) Data Analytics Acceleration Library'
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/daal
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/daal/setup/PUBLIC_KEY.PUB
debuglevel=10
enabled=1
```

But, from this morning, the yum install command (`sudo yum install intel-daal-core-2018.1-163`) fails with:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from intel-mkl-core-2018.1-163: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Gpg Keys not imported, cannot verify repomd.xml for repo intel-mkl-core-2018.1-163
```

However, if I stop checking the gpg keys, namely - I change the repo files to:

```
[intel-mkl-core-2018.1-163]
name='Intel(R) Intel Math Kernel Library'
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=0
#gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl/setup/PUBLIC_KEY.PUB
debuglevel=10
enabled=1


[intel-daal-core-2018.1-163]
name='Intel(R) Data Analytics Acceleration Library'
baseurl=https://yum.repos.intel.com/daal
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
repo_gpgcheck=0
#gpgkey=https://yum.repos.intel.com/daal/setup/PUBLIC_KEY.PUB
debuglevel=10
enabled=1
```

And do:

```
sudo yum clean all ; sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Then `sudo yum install intel-daal-core-2018.1-163` is successful.

Googling didn't find any notice from Intel that they changed something.
Anyone knows what's the reason for the yum failure of gpg keys?

Comment: what happens with `rpm --import https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl/setup/PUBLIC_KEY.PUB` ?

Comment: After intel fixed the issue, @user3788685, the `rpm --import https://yum.repos.intel.com/mkl/setup/PUBLIC_KEY.PUB` imports the key without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a problem Intel had with the daal/mkl gpg keys.
The problem is fixed now, namely, if you run the following, you shouldn't have any errors:

```
  sudo yum clean all ; sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum 
  sudo yum install intel-mkl-core-2018.1-163 --downloadonly -y
  sudo yum install intel-daal-core-2018.1-163 --downloadonly -y
```